# Как создать цикл с рандомным умножением чисел?

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Вот такой:

```
import random

a = random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
b = random.choice([19, 28, 37, 46, 55, 64, 73, 82, 94, 100])
c = a * b

while c > 0:
    print(c)
```

Но в этом примере while выводит бесконечно первый полученный результат. А как сделать, чтобы  при каждом выводе подбирались новые рандомные числа?

Comment: может быть потому, что этот результат нужно КАЖДЫЙ РАЗ заново получать в цикле?

Comment: это да, но как условие c > 0 тогда добавить?

Comment: куда добавить??

Comment: c - это результат умножения a на b (c = a*b). Если c>10, то завершать цикл

Comment: так c неизвестен до начала цикла, как его сравнивать

Comment: "азы дальше некуда". Такое вот вообще неэтично писать, тут для того люди и задают вопросы

Comment: нет, тут люди на для того задают вопросы. тут люди задают вопросы, если у них трудности в решении задач, а не если им лень почитать учебник.

Comment: а еще похоже, что тут люди пишут язвительные комментарии не разобравшись в вопросе

Comment: в любом случае, уже неважно, сам разобрался

Comment: ну как же "сам разобрался", если разобрался за вас я, и все в комментариях написал?

Comment: посоветовать перед циклом сравнивать значение переменной, которое получается внутри этого цикла. Гениальный совет! Спасибо.

Comment: это у вас оно присваивается ТОЛЬКО внутри цикла. а у людей с логикой, оно присваивается перед циклом, а в цикле проверяется и, если нужно, присваивается снова. тут даже программистом быть не нужно, это простейшая логика. только мозг включить и все.

Comment: Буду рад, если вы со своей гениальной логикой покажете как присвоить изменяемое рандомное значение переменной до начала цикла. Я могу сделать рандом до цикла, но в самом цикле это значение не будет изменяться, если следовать логике из вашего примера

Answer (score 1):

В общем так:

```
import random

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [19, 28, 37, 46, 55, 64, 73, 82, 94, 100]

while True:
    c = random.choice(a) * random.choice(b)
    print(c)
    if c > 500:
        break
```